# Find $\operatorname{dist}(f,A)$ in $A = \left\{ ax^2 : a \ge 0 \right\} \subseteq \left( C[0,1], d_{\sup} \right) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Find $\operatorname{dist}(f,A)$ where $f(x) = x$ and $A = \left\{ ax^2 : a  \ge 0 \right\}  \subseteq \left( C[0,1], d_{\sup} \right)  $ and $d_{\sup}(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$

I solved it, and in one moment I recived that $\operatorname{dist}(f,A) = \inf\left\{\frac{1}{4a}: a \ge 0 \right\} $. This infimum of course is equal to $0$.

Can you check, is my result good?

Comment: It's not. For $a > 1$, you have $d(f,ax^2) \geqslant a-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\ge 0$ let $g_a(x)=ax^2$, so that $A=\{g_a:a\ge 0\}$. Then

$$d_{\sup}(f,g_a)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|x-ax^2|\;.$$

For $a>0$ the function $(f-g_a)(x)=x-ax^2$ is increasing on $\left[0,\frac1{2a}\right]$ and attains its maximum at $x=\frac1{2a}$. If $0\le a\le\frac12$, the function is increasing on $[0,1]$ and attains its maximum on $[0,1]$ of $1-a$ at $x=1$.

If $a\ge\frac12$, the maximum is $$\frac1{2a}-a\left(\frac1{2a}\right)^2=\frac1{4a}\;,$$ and it is attained on $[0,1]$. However, the function decreases to the right of $\frac1{2a}$, so the maximum of $|f-g_a|$ on $[0,1]$ is actually

$$\max\left\{\frac1{4a},|(f-g_a)(1)|\right\}=\max\left\{\frac1{4a},a-1\right\}\;.$$

Solving $\frac1{4a}=a-1$ yields $4a^2-4a-1=0$ and $a=\frac{1+\sqrt2}2$; for convenience let $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt2}2$. Then

$$\max\left\{\frac1{4a},a-1\right\}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac1{4a},&\text{if }\frac12\le a\le\alpha\\\\
a-1,&\text{if }a\ge\alpha\;,
\end{cases}$$

and

$$d_{\sup}(f,g_a)=\begin{cases}
1-a,&\text{if }0\le a\le\dfrac12\\\\
\dfrac1{4a},&\text{if }\dfrac12\le a\le\alpha\\\\
a-1,&\text{if }a\ge\alpha\;.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly

$$d_{\sup}(f,g_a)\ge\begin{cases}
\dfrac12,&\text{if }0\le a\le\dfrac12\\\\
\dfrac1{4\alpha},&\text{if }\dfrac12\le a\le\alpha\\\\
\alpha-1,&\text{if }a\ge\alpha\;,
\end{cases}$$

with equality achieved in each case, so

$$\operatorname{dist}(f,A)=\inf_{a\ge 0}d_{\sup}(f,g_a)=\min\left\{\frac12,\frac1{4\alpha},\alpha-1\right\}=\frac1{4\alpha}=\alpha-1=\frac{\sqrt2-1}2\;.$$

The point of $A$ nearest $f$ is $g_\alpha$.